# Eclipse jxmaps no valid license found

Tags: java, jxmaps

I have imported jxmaps to eclipse. But I get the error when running the code (which i copied from online to test the import worked to ensure there wouldn't be an error within the code):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.teamdev.jxmaps.internal.internal.ipc.m.a(SourceFile:44)
    at com.teamdev.jxmaps.internal.v.<init>(SourceFile:53)
    at com.teamdev.jxmaps.internal.v.<clinit>(SourceFile:23)
    at com.teamdev.jxmaps.internal.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:136)
    at com.teamdev.jxmaps.MapBrowser.<init>(SourceFile:27)
    at com.teamdev.jxmaps.swing.MapView.<init>(SourceFile:42)
    at StreetViewExample.<init>(StreetViewExample.java:9)
    at StreetViewExample.main(StreetViewExample.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JxMaps license check failed: No valid license found.
```

I assume this is the same process with all external libraries, but how do you resolve this issue?

This is where I imported the libraries if this helps.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you need a license.jar file, to get it working. But checking out the developers website, it seems, that they stop supporting the library in May 2020: https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps

Comment: ok thanks, do u think i should find another google maps api then?

Comment: I don't believe, that the are still sell licenses. So if you don't have one, you won't be able to use it. In this case you probably want to switch to another library, which can render maps in JavaFx, because you won't get this library running. I don't knwo what kind of application you are building and I never had to implement any map service in to my Java application, but there still some other libraries available. Did you tought maybe of using another map provider? Google Maps is most commenly used, but also OpenStreetMaps is good and has many JavaFX libraries.